# A puzzle in 140 characters

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Your final answer will respond to the question "Why don't I like Twitter that much?"

Like usual, I'll confirm any sub-answers if you find them

[image]

[Here's](https://twitter.com/lax_chiller/status/895745299750236160) the link to the puzzle on Twitter.

Here's the text of the puzzle:

> ❄#♠
>   255879⠗⠕⠞⠼⠁⠊⠉:⠺⠠⠰⠶⠮∞WᒧO3>H∽UO)
>   Z⊢せம佛أر➪ᓭܜ⚡ﺪトΛíĆẸİĿMṈOṖ$ŦŪVYA
>   hot new vow⊔N⌶ⅽ✜ዐᛊfirsts✒
>   ➖☄V२-ƧΞ⊕ꘜ⊞।
>   Ʌ⎕META:…|#/|@…:@**¢#1¢1:/

Comment: The braille begins 'rot 19'

Comment: Bounties should be available for both questions and answers.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4862/25966

Comment: We need to get this to 140 upvotes.

Comment: Actually, with newlines, it is 144 chars.

Comment: Please do a writeup!

Comment: You'll have to do a puzzle in 280 characters now :P

Comment: It's no longer Twitter... It's X.

Answer (score 303, accepted):

**NOTE: If you upvote this, please upvote the puzzle itself too! It took *far* more effort to make than my solution did.**

❄#♠255879

> This is a word square:
>  `PAW`
>  `ICE`
>  `NET`
>  Extract the letters in the positions 2, 5, 5, 8, 7, 9 on a phone keypad to get **ACCENT**.

⠗⠕⠞⠼⠁⠊⠉:⠺⠠⠰⠶⠮

> The first part (before the colon) says "ROT193".
>  Logically, that's ROT180 + ROT13.
>  So, do that to everything after the colon - flip it upside down (rot180), decode as Braille, then rot13 it to get **ATONE**.

∞WᒧO3>H∽UO)Z⊢

> Turn your head sideways - it reads as "BELOW VISCOUNT", and the rank below Viscount is **BARON**.

せம佛أر➪ᓭܜ⚡ﺪトΛí

> Start with the section left of the arrow. Those are characters from various languages: SE, MA, PHO, and RE. So we interpret the things *right* of the arrow as flag semaphore to get **COLOGNE**.

ĆẸİĿMṈOṖ\$ŦŪVY

> You can rearrange these to get `ĆOṈ$ŪMṖŦİVẸĿY`. The accents there are Morse code for TORI, and "Tori, consumptively" is a crossword clue (though oddly phrased) for **DONUTS**.

A hot new vow

> This is just a cryptic clue for **OATH**. *(Thanks, Sp3000!)*

⊔N⌶ⅽ✜ዐᛊfirsts

> This says "Unicode firsts", but in a weird way. Take the characters that make up "Unicode", look them up in Unicode, and take the first letters of the official names to get **SLASHER**.

✒➖☄

> This is simply a rebus.
>  Before the minus sign we have SNAIL TACO METRO PEN KEY STOP HATCH. After, we have NAIL COMET OPEN KEYS TOP HAT. Removing the latter from the former gives us S[nail]TA[comet]R[open][keys][tophat]CH, or **STARCH**.

V२-ƧΞ⊕ꘜ⊞।Ʌ⎕

> The middle symbol (that looks like a circled plus sign) means "exclusive or" - basically, overlap and remove anything that's black in both symbols. Do that to the six symbols on either side and you get the word **THRASH**.

META:…|#/|@…:@**¢#1¢1:/

> All the words are made up of a punctuation mark with two letters inserted (or on the sides). For instance, COLO(g)N(e) --> COLON and (t)H(r)ASH --> HASH. Those punctuation marks appear twice each in the text after "META:". Replace the two occurrences with the two extra letters, in order.
>  [image]
>  You don't like Twitter because it has **NOT ENOUGH CHARACTER**!

Comment: Off the scale!!

Comment: Where is that +10 button?

Comment: I wish I could watch a recording of your train of thought solving this.

Comment: Amazing but as far as I can see your answer doesn't account for "#♠", characters four through seven. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @pateksan It's part of the word square. (A word square is a square arrangement of letters where you can see words reading both across and down. Those are the "down" words.)