# Already Solved Puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Screenshots of the solution from my latest puzzle:

[image]

Comment: Wait... wait... is this a puzzle? Doesn't it need steganography tag?

Comment: I believe there's a reverse puzzling tag, so could you add that so people don't get confused?

Comment: You have one weird shaped computer if this a one screenshot...

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil You must just have small monitor, my screen [look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl860.jpg)

Comment: @Kruga, ah, one of the new SmartPhones which you strap to your legs and your back, right?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Screenshot of the wrapup from your latest puzzle:

(Huh, some of the *less* useful text turned red when I screenshotted it! That's strange.)

> [image]

---

Okay, here's how we *really* did it.

It's initially unclear how to attack the puzzle as a whole, but some of the parts are more direct than others, so we can start with those...

The cryptic in **Part 3** can be solved mostly normally, however, there are two gimmicks involved.

> Firstly, each clue has a word that must be "beheaded" before the clue will work. Secondly, some clues provide the incorrect enumeration (it becomes clear why when coming to fit them to a grid):
>
>  Grab a circle holding **t**in counting machines (5): *_AB A CI_*
>  Court-worth Nascar Jr. **h**eating 60s diet cola (<del>6</del> **7**): *DA(TAB)LE*
>  Every one **e**strange ache (<del>3</del> **4**): *EACH**
>  Before person **o**rating epitaph, initially (3): *(PRE)_*
>  Price label **p**receded pistol (3): *GAT<*
>  Listen to successor of musical with "**P**aint Got No" (<del>3</del> **4**): *HAIR* ("heir")
>  Bad **o**zone rig resetting, like a scale. (<del>6</del> **7**): *ZEROING**
>  Adept **s**hooters hold profundity (5): *_DEPT H_*
>  Saying "Great scott!" **i**rises after best grade (5): *A+DAGE<*
>  Captain Morgan rival king, for example, **t**enters one who likes both (<del>6</del> **7**): B(A+CARD)I
>  **E**A hot new vow (<del>3</del> **4**): *OATH** (used in one of OP's [previous puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/54165/a-puzzle-in-140-characters))
>  Top of **o**pen hat (3): *CAP* (ddef)
>  Brilliant TV brain **f**altered (<del>6</del> **7**): *VIBRANT**
>  **P**leaders of law enforcement indight gravely heinous actress Vivien (5): *(LEIGH)_*
>  Low digit ripped right **r**out (3): *TO(-r)E*
>  Chips front off middle of **O**men (<del>3</del> **4**): *(-c)HIPS*
>
>  Treating the clues as coming in standard across/down order, it's relatively easy to fit them to the grid, as shown above, but with extra letters (where longer than the given enumeration) extending outside the grid. Reading these off clockwise from the top, gives the answer: **OVERSIZE**.
>  Also note that the extra letters in the clues, when taken in order, spell **opposite of pro**, giving us **CON** (to be used later).

The cryptic clue/rebus words in **Part 6** can be identified from the errata/advice. Some were relatively obvious/limited, and once the pattern emerged the rest became simpler. Specifically:

> [&lit from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptic_crossword#%22&lit.%22) => *EGG*
>  "Emotion" cluephrase => *EMOTIVE*
>  Sparkly and pretty => *GEM*
>  Arthropod developmental phases => *[INSTAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instar)*
>  Technically an artery => *VEIN*
>  Final/physical/oral exams => *MEDICAL*
>  Relating to "night vision" => *ARMED*
>
>  Using the above we can see that the words fall into an overlapping pattern:
>  *EG(G EM)OTI(VE IN)ST(AR MED)ICAL*
>
>  So, whilst we don't have access to the "pluses and minuses on the flag" mentioned in the last step of this part, it doesn't take too much to realise that we can subtract the overlapping parts (EGG + EMOTIVE + INSTAR + MEDICAL - GEM - VEIN - ARMED) such that the remaining letters spell **EGOTISTICAL**.

Thanks to our earlier work, we have a partial lead on **Part 7**:

> The clues here talk about trigrams (three-letter sequences) and "stolen" parts, which we can assume are stolen from other parts of the puzzle. We happen to have found one of these in part 3 (the *CON* we derived from the extra clue letters). There's also mention of another one in Part 2 ("one part is used for a later puzzle"). This means the word must be of the form `[???][CON][???][???]` or `[???][???][CON][???]`, with the bracketed parts being wordlike. The only thematic answer here is **DISCONTENTED**.

At this point a solver would realize that the seven parts are themed around:

> The 7 Deadly Sins, and the answers describe someone who overindulges in that puzzle's sin. The meta explanation mentions two different orderings, and it seems that the answer lengths increase by 1 as you go down from part 1 to part 7. With these heavy constraints and a bit of additional info from the descriptions, we can now figure out the other answers.
>
>  **Part 1** has "metal in it"; the only word meaning "overindulging in greed" with a metal inside is **STINGY**.
>  **Part 2** can't be figured out on its own but **PASSIVE** is all that will work when backsolving from the meta answer. However, it is still thematically described in the clue ("allows us to be extra lazy").
>  **Part 4** has a supposed typo, and the only synonym of "angry" that has an A after an R (where the A could plausibly be typoed to an I) is **IRRITABLE**.
>  **Part 5** mentions "inserting into a woman" and is pretty clearly the lust puzzle, so the answer **LASCIVIOUS** fits (having "LASS" around the outside).
>
>  The first letters of the answers spell `S?OILED`, so the answer is **SPOILED**.

Comment: For obvious reasons, this answer needs to be voted up to +13.

Comment: Figured I couldn't complain if I wasn't willing to do something about it, so I've made an edit to include the other pertinent info. Hope you don't mind...