# What letter is this?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, history, emoji

The answer to this puzzle is a single letter:

⚙️♠️ ⛑➕ PN

What letter is this?

Hint 1:

> This puzzle is inspired by this puzzle: [A puzzle in 140 characters](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/54165/9385)

Hint 2:

> /  =

Comment: Are the spaces between " ", "P ", and "N " intentional?

Comment: @MatthewJensen Sorry, my mistake. I just did an edit to fix

Comment: Jeez, I'd love to know how someone takes on this puzzle and reasons an answer out of it - because it just looks like a series of completely unrelated emojis to me.

Answer (score 11):

The letter is:

> **L**. (I'm actually not quite sure, see below.)

The first twelve characters ...

> ... are actually two blocks of six characters, separated by a space. The emojis in the first block depict a **cog**, an **ace**, a **ram**, a **car** an **[oca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxalis_tuberosa)** and a **gem**. The emojis in the second block show **eta** ("estimated time of arrival", probably not a Greek letter we're looking for), first **aid**, a **red** tomato, an **ear**, a **tie** and **add**.
>
>  As in the referenced "puzzle in 140 characters", these can be arranged into two word squares:
>
> ```
>          C O G           E T A
>          A C E           A I D
>          R A M           R E D
> ```

The football ...

> ... refers to the [NFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Football_League). Some of the words in the square can be found in the names of NFL teams:
>
>    • Las Vegas R**aid**ers
>    • LA **Ram**s
>    • Chicago B**ear**s
>    • Arizona **Car**dinals
>
>  If we highlight only the rows and columns with the words found in the teams above, we get:
>
> ```
>          C . .           E . .
>          A . .           A I D
>          R A M           R . .
> ```
>
> (Hm. I thought this should give two L's. The Redskins now call themselves the Washington Football Team, so **red** should probably not be highlighted, but **aid** is right there in Raiders. The second square could be a T, because it is not really specified what is a row and what a column, but transposing the first square doesn't give a letter.
>
> But there's the "P (muted speaker) N" still to account for. This could mean permutation, but swapping rows or columns in a grid with one full column and one full row can lead only to L or T.)

Comment: Nice work on the word squares. Is there anything in those word squares you found a bit strange…?

Comment: There is one emoji that is the «odd one out» in each word square, which one are those?